# Advantage of wrapping classes in DLLs

Tags: c++, dll, export

I've just finished a phase in my project where I wrote a small infrastructure to carry out a certain task, made of a core class with several auxiliary classes.
The C++'ness is quite basic - single inheritance, some STL containers, that's it.
No threads - client runs the show.

What I would like to do now is wrap it all up in a DLL, version it, and use
it as a standalone unit. I'd like that seperation in order to track changes and
development better, and perhaps for other projects as well.

As I don't have experience with classes in DLLs, I would like to hear yours:
What's your approach to this problem?

Specifically:

- Is it worth the trouble?
- Do you do that often or not at all?
- What about compatibiliy issues (like clients compiled using a different compiler)?

I'm not really asking for a debate (though that's the probable outcome), but rather an advice from experience.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: "What's your approach to this problem?" - if there is a problem / concern that you have it might to just clarify what this is as its not entirely clear from the question that anything is actually *wrong*.

Comment: @Justin, basically what I want is to have a single point of entry (header/lib/dll package) instead of about 6 pairs of h/cpp files when I want/need in the future to use that part in other places.

Comment: @Alevy, instead of making a DLL, why don't you use them as a static lib ?

Comment: @João, thanks, it actually does seem like the way to go in my scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it hard to see any benefit with this. I can see plenty of problems:

- No type checking across a DLL boundary. Any version mismatches will result in runtime failures, harder to detect than compile time failures.
- Extra deployment headaches. You may be tempted to update some but not all modules and so deal with complex dependencies.
- All clients that want to use these DLLs must use the same compiler.

Only make this change if you can identify benefits that outweigh the negatives.

Comment: It's fairly common practice to build large project as a series of DLLs, I guess the advantages are reduced intermediate build times and smaller binary size where several executable components re-use the same code. In such configurations, these DLLs can be considered to be compatible only with the specific build that they were created part of.

Comment: +1. The advantage of packaging/separation is reduced in light of the compatiblity and usablity issues. I'm gonna drop this idea.

Answer (score 1):

C++ code is not binary compatible between compilers, it's generally no use creating DLLs exposing C++ classes that aren't built as part of the project that uses them.

If you want to create a Windows DLL with a well-defined object-oriented interface that the rest of the world can use, make it a COM inproc server.

Comment: I have a similar scenario and I have to choose from 1). Having a static library or 2). having a COM server. I am not sure of implications of opting for COM server over static library. Please throw some light.

Comment: COM inproc server is a DLL, so it's dynamically bound to your executable - with a static library you have to link it with the rest of your program to create an executable in the first place, but then the library does not have to be "installed" in any way on the target system. A COM server needs to be installed, meaning (in the case of inproc) the DLL has to be present on the system, but also it has to be "registered" so it may be located by class ID or name. Also, you do not make calls using full-featured C++ into a COM server, but you are only allowed to use COM's object model.

Comment: The advantage is that COM is guaranteed to be binary stable, so if you distribute a component as a COM DLL it will be usable by clients compiled with any (COM compliant) compiler, any libraries etc. pretty much forever. With a static library it's quite the opposite - it's specific to the version of toolchain and any libraries used, so it's pretty much useless as a format to distribute components to a larger audience.